# Unable to set ringtone through code for Android M

Tags: java, android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I am developing an application that will randomly set a ringtone from a list of tones user has already selected.

While my code works for Android N and above, I am facing problems with Android M and below. I've search a lot for the solution. But could not find any.

Here is my code snippet that is setting the ringtone.

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),
                                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                                uri);
```

Here is the [link to entire file](https://github.com/codersam8/RingtoneChanger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/ssurinen/ringtonechanger/MainActivity.java).

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the error log that is generated while the application is running

```
11-11 09:09:32.914 3292-3292/? W/Binder_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:32): avc: denied { read } for path="/storage/emulated/0/iphone6.mp3" dev="fuse" ino=23 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
11-11 09:09:32.935 1611-3697/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 336)
11-11 09:09:32.935 1611-3697/system_process I/ActivityThread: Removing dead content provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@b69350e
11-11 09:09:32.937 1611-3697/system_process W/ActivityManager: unstableProviderDied: caller 1000 says ContentProviderConnection{ca0b2f/com.android.externalstorage/.ExternalStorageProvider->1611:system/1000 s0/0 u1/1 +23ms} died, but we don't agree
11-11 09:09:32.934 3292-3292/? W/Binder_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:33): avc: denied { read } for path="/storage/emulated/0/iphone6.mp3" dev="fuse" ino=23 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
11-11 09:09:32.954 1611-3697/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 336)
11-11 09:09:32.954 1611-3697/system_process W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed opening content provider: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aiphone6.mp3
11-11 09:09:32.963 1611-3697/system_process W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from (null) (pid=1328, uid=1013) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
11-11 09:09:32.964 1328-1680/? E/MediaPlayerService: Couldn't open fd for content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aiphone6.mp3
11-11 09:09:32.965 1611-3697/system_process E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
11-11 09:09:32.965 1611-3697/system_process D/Ringtone: Problem opening; delegating to remote player
11-11 09:09:32.954 3293-3293/? W/Binder_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:34): avc: denied { read } for path="/storage/emulated/0/iphone6.mp3" dev="fuse" ino=23 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance

I've searched for how to get `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission. What I have gathered is it's security level is of `signature` and only applications that come with android can have that permission.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your error properly 
Here i can see `requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`
and also you have to use runtime permission for those permission

Comment: I have tried adding the permission already. The issue still persists even after acquiring therpermission.